# Тире или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

"Столько всего произошло (-) и личного, и в творчестве".

Answer (score 1):

В вашем предложении не надо ни тире, ни двоеточие. Нет никаких условий для их постановки. Возможно, вы считаете, что *"всего"* - обобщающее слово, но нет. Оно означает скорее события, а *"и личного, и в творчестве"* - признаки этих событий. Здесь можно подумать об обособлении второй части, так как главное слово выражено местоимением, обстоятельства стоят после главного слова и дистанция в виде сказуемого (все четыре признака обособления). Я думаю, стоит поставить запятую, то бишь предложение должно выглядеть так: ***"Столько всего произошло, и личного, и в творчестве"***

Comment: Если не обращать внимания на то, что однородные члены употреблены не совсем правильно,то тире здесь возможно. Позволяет интонация с длинной паузой.
 
Местоимение всего, Валентин, является главным  для слов "и личного, и в творчестве" только при условии, если это определения (одно согласованное, другое нет): всего (какого?).  Тогда обособление запятой понятно. Но если "в творчестве" - это обстоятельство, как Вы пишете, то главным для него будет глагол, т.е. слово "произошло".

Answer (score 0):

Лучше - с тире. Интонационно оно просится. А грамматически - разобрано у [@EkaterinaKas](/users/997/ekaterinakashtanova4).